# ModuleNotFoundError seen after the first time a job is run on a Ray cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, ray

I'm running a script which imports a module from a file in the same directory. The first time I run the script after starting the cluster the script runs as expected. Any subsequent times I run the script I get the following error:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ex_cls'

How do I get Ray to recognize modules I'm importing after the first run?

I am using Ray 1.11.0 on a redhat Linux cluster.

Here are my scripts. Both are located in the /home/ray_experiment directory:

--ex_main.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ray_experiment')
from ex_cls import monitor_wrapper

import ray
ray.init(address='auto')

from ray.util.multiprocessing import Pool

def main(): 

    pdu_infos = range(10)

    with Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(monitor_wrapper, [pdu for pdu in pdu_infos])
       
        for pdu_info, result in zip(pdu_infos, results):
            print(pdu_info, result)
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

--ex_cls.py

```
import sys
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint
import collections
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ray_experiment')
MonitorResult = collections.namedtuple('MonitorResult', 'key task_time')

def monitor_wrapper(args):
    start = time()
    rando = randint(0, 200)
    lst = []
    for i in range(10000 * rando):
        lst.append(i)
    pause = 1
    sleep(pause)
    return MonitorResult(args, time() - start)
```

-- Edit

I've found that by adding these two environment variables I no longer see the ModuleNotFoundError.

export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/ray_experiment/"

export RAY_RUNTIME_ENV_WORKING_DIR_CACHE_SIZE_GB=0

Is there another solution that doesn't require disabling the working environment caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Ray's worker processes may be run from different working directories than your driver python script. In fact, on a cluster, they may even be run from different machines. This is coupled by the fact that python looks for the module based on a relative path (to be precise, cloudpickle serializes definitions in other modules by reference).

The "intended" solution to this problem is to use [runtime environments](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/handling-dependencies.html).

In particular, you should do `ray.init(address='auto', runtime_env={"working_dir": "./"})` when starting Ray to ensure that the module is passed to other processes.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for similar error I found this in Ray docs:
https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/handling-dependencies.html#library-development

Adding `__init__.py` to root of these directories and handing them over with this kwarg solved my issue with ModuleNotFoundError. Another part of solution is to install all requirements to the container the ray is running in and probably starting it in same workdir as app (or passing workdir in runtime kwargs)

To answer OPs problem I would try something like this:

```
import ex_cls
# it cannot pass classes, just whole module
ray.init(address='auto', runtime_env={"py_modules": [ex_cls]})
```